# Metaballs disappearing when renamed

Tags: meta-objects

So like I said in the title I have an issue with metaballs disappearing when renamed, only leaving the outline visible. For renaming I followed this guide https://youtu.be/Y7R2_F-ZukQ?t=330 and I do not get the same result. When I rename them back to Mball, they reappear. When I try this process in a new clean file it works without any problems. Does anyone possibly know what might be causing this to happen?

This is the new name, it still follows the naming guidelines:

[image]

But I get this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out what was causing the issue for me :D The number in the new name I was renaming the metaballs to. When I renamed them to Slime instead of Slime1 works fine. Just leaving it here in case anyone else has this problem. :) But any additional knowledge on this topic is welcome.